# Ignore form field to serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am passing my form to searlize to make an ajax call. There is only one text area which I don't want to searlize and I am ignoring it with following text but its not working find and the text area always get serlized.

```
$("#my_form :textarea[name!='terms']").serialize()
```

Comment: We can't help you with selectors unless we know what we're selecting from. What does your HTML look like? More specifically, what does #my_form look like? It also seems like removing/moving the colon would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a class to the textarea that you don't want to serialize.  Such as `ignore`.

Then just use `$("#my_form textarea:not(.ignore)").serialize()` and you will be ready to go.

**JS Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/s5xr3shu/

Comment: I think his problem is that there is only one textarea he doesn't want to serialize, and he doesn't want to put a class on all the others.

Comment: or add the class to the fields you don't want to serialize: `$("#myForm input:not(.skipdata)").serialize();`

Comment: @skibulk exactly I am seeking solution for that

Comment: Just added a jsfiddle that proves it works